# integration over a circle using residues

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

We are asked to solve the following integral using residue theorem

$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z\sin^2z} dz$.

I was able to show that it has one pole of order 3 inside $|z|=1$ given by $z=0$. We know that
$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z\sin^2z} dz = 2\pi i Res\left(\frac{1}{z\sin^2z},0\right).$$
where,
$Res\left(\frac{1}{z\sin^2z},0\right) = \displaystyle\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{2!}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(\frac{z^2}{\sin^2z}\right)\right)$.

The problem is that this limit seem to not exist with my computation. Is my approach right?

Comment: You should try recalculating the derivative (maybe check with Wolfram Alpha or some other CAS). It's limit does exist, and should equal $(1/2)(2/3) = 1/3$. Alternatively you can find the Laurent expansion of the original integrand and read the $z^{-1}$ coefficient from that, as Gribouillis does in their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Taylor expansion when $z\to 0$
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{z\sin^2z} = \frac{1}{z^3}\left(1 -\frac{z^2}{6} + o(z^2)\right)^{-2}
=\frac{1}{z^3}+\frac{1}{3z} + o\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Can you explain a bit what happened in the second equality?

Comment: Its okay, I already get it. thanks